# gcloud auth login issue 403 access denied when trying to run bigquery

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, gcloud

EDIT: seems like this is only an issue for tables based on google drive files. I am using auth login, the jobs show up in bigquery UI as being run by me as the owner, but return this error despite the fact I should have full perms for this data and the files it is based on.

I am having an issue getting gcloud to run bigquery and it is returning the error:

google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.

I have tried all the various login commands:

> gcloud auth application-default login

> gcloud auth login

I then get taken to the browser and grant access permissions, everything seems fine, but I still get the same error.

When running the following my account shows up fine, I can see my login credentials as a JSON file, but I just cannot understand why it is saying I do not have access.

```html
gloud auth list
```

I can go into bigquery and see the query being requested by myself as the owner, and then I can run the same query in the bigquery console, but it just does not work when requested via the script.

Here is the code I am running.  Multiple people have run this code, confirms it works, and they have not done anything different to me.

I assume I have done something wrong with the gcloud login but struggling to understand what.

```html
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
from google.cloud import bigquery



def load_data(query_file):
    with open(query_file, "r+") as query_file:
        query = query_file.read()

    
    client = bigquery.Client(project = "my-data")

    df = client.query(query).result().to_dataframe()

    return df

def load_current_es(ttl=60 * 60 * 540):
    """Get current ES names and pod
    Args:
        None
    Returns:
        pd.Dataframe
    """
    columns = {"full_name": "str"}
    df = load_data("data/current_es.sql")
    assert len(df) > 0, "Dataframe for current ES is empty"

    # correct data types
    df = df.astype(dtype=columns)

    return df

df = load_current_es()

print(df.head())
```

Comment: Is the table/view you are querying an external table based on a google drive file?  If so it’s like you need to authorize the SA you are using

Comment: Hi Daniel, very astute.  After digging around it does seem to be only files which are based on google drive files causing an issue.  Sorry but I am pretty rubbish at this, are there docs somewhere on how to go about that?

Answer (score 1):

So in the end this turned out to be a gcloud authentification issue.

I had run `gcloud auth login` and `gcloud auth application-default login --scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery` and thought this had granted drive access, but was still receiving error 403 drive access denied on tables linked to drive files.  It was strange as it showed in the BQ ui that the jobs were being called with me as the owner, but perms did not seem to be being applied as expected.

The solution was to also run `gcloud auth login --enable-gdrive-access` and then it now gives access to all tables.